# Заменить из одного array данными из другого

Tags: php

Есть два **Array**

Первый

```
    [11] => 565;Duo Pellet N
[12] => 565;Duo Pellet N
[13] => 565;Duo Pellet N
[14] => 565;Duo Pellet N
[15] => 565;Duo Pellet N
[16] => 565;Duo Pellet N
[17] => 565;Duo Pellet N
[18] => 167;НЕУС-В
[19] => 167;НЕУС-В
[20] => 167;НЕУС-В
[21] => 167;НЕУС-В
[22] => 167;НЕУС-В
[23] => 167;НЕУС-В
[24] => 190;UNI-MAX
[25] => 190;UNI-MAX
[26] => 190;UNI-MAX
[27] => 190;UNI-MAX
[28] => 190;UNI-MAX
[29] => 190;UNI-MAX
```

Второй

```
[193] => 7729;CIC 
[194] => 7730;КОТВ-100 М
[195] => 7692;AIR Pellet 36 кВт
[196] => 7683;UNI-MAX
[197] => 7694;AIR Pellet  50 кВт
[198] => 7689;Клапан безопасности
[199] => 7690;AIR Pellet 15 кВт
```

Разберем пример. Берем из первого Array `[25] => 190;UNI-MAX` и находим по `UNI-MAX` во втором Array `[196] => 7683;UNI-MAX` и заменяем все в первом Array `190;UNI-MAX` на второй `7683;UNI-MAX` при этом сложность оставить в первом точно такую же сортировку.

Comment: с такой структурой массива вам только регулярными выражениями извращаться нужно

Answer (score 0):

Назовем первый массив `$src`, а второй `$replacement`;

Насколько можно судить, вторая часть строки во втором массиве - уникальна. Так что его надо привести к такому виду, чтобы вместро значения `7729;CIC` получился массив `CIC => 7729`. Сделать это в принципе не сложно, например:

```
$matches = array_column(array_map(function($v){ 
                           return explode(';', $v);
                     }, $replacement), 0, 1);
```

А дальше пройтись по строкам первого массива, также разбивать их на части и делать сопоставление с массивом соответствий:

```
$result = array_map(function($v) use ($matches) {
                 [$id, $x] = explode(';', $v);
                 return isset($matches[$x]) ? "{$matches[$x]};$x" : $v;
            }, $src);
```